# How I should access webcam connected to raspberry pi in my laptop (python) via web(wifi)?

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, remote-access, webcam

Hi? I'm making some camera-based application using raspberry pi.

Since rpi is not as powerful as I had expected, I decided to process the image in my laptop.

Unfortunately, it is unable to connect the camera and my laptop directly.

I would like to read an image from camera on rpi, and send the image to my laptop (via web server using wifi) and process the image on my laptop (in python programming, opencv or some related libraries are preferable).

How should I do this? I could find some related examples, but all of them did not fit perfect with my application...